# " warning.indexOf is not a function" rollup.js

Tags: angular, angular2-aot, rollupjs

Am getting below error message  with rollup.config.js file

> �   warning.indexOf is not a function

**rollup.config.js**

```
 import nodeResolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve'
 import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import uglify from 'rollup-plugin-uglify'

  //paths are relative to the execution path
export default {
  entry: 'src/main-aot.js',
  dest: 'aot/dist/build.js', // output a single application bundle
  sourceMap: true,
  sourceMapFile: 'aot/dist/build.js.map',
 format: 'iife',
 onwarn: function (warning) {
// Skip certain warnings

// should intercept ... but doesn't in some rollup versions
if (warning.code === 'THIS_IS_UNDEFINED') { return; }
// intercepts in some rollup versions
if (warning.indexOf("The 'this' keyword is equivalent to 'undefined'") > -1) { return; }
if (warning.indexOf("Use of `eval` ") > -1) {
  return;
}
// console.warn everything else
console.warn(warning.message);
 },
 plugins: [
  nodeResolve({ jsnext: true, module: true }),
  commonjs({
  include: 'node_modules/rxjs/**',
}),
uglify()
]
}
```

**pacakge.json**

> "rollup": "^0.41.6",
>      "rollup-plugin-commonjs": "^8.0.2",
>      "rollup-plugin-node-resolve": "^3.0.0",
>       "rollup-plugin-uglify": "^1.0.1",

Answer (score 0):

It seems warning itself is rather an object than a string.
So I changed the line with the .indexOf statement to the folling:

```
if ( warning.message.indexOf("The 'this' keyword is equivalent to 'undefined'") > -1 ) { return; }
```

So the error is avoided, but I don't know whether this is the correct solution. Because when I then try to rollup my angular2 app I'm getting several error of "not exported".
But you can give it a try, maybe it helps you.